# Android - Rollover text on button

Tags: android

I'm creating a rollover effect with regards to a button background and its text. I've been able to create the rollover effect for the background such that when button is in a pressed or focused state then the background is changed from black to yellow. Below is how I did this:

in my fragment:

```
btnLogin.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_login);
```

here's the background resource i.e. btn_login.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

     <item android:state_pressed="true"
           android:drawable="@drawable/btn_loginrollover" /> <!-- pressed -->

     <item android:state_focused="true"
           android:drawable="@drawable/btn_loginrollover" /> <!-- focused -->

     <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_logindefault" /> <!-- default -->

 </selector>
```

btn_logindeault.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--  res/drawable/rounded_edittext.xml -->
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle" 
       android:padding="10dp">

       <solid android:color="#000000"/>

       <corners
         android:bottomRightRadius="4dp"
         android:bottomLeftRadius="4dp"
         android:topLeftRadius="4dp"
         android:topRightRadius="4dp"/>

       <gradient
         android:startColor="#000000"
         android:centerColor="#000000"
         android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
         android:angle="90"/>      
</shape>
```

btn_loginrollover.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--  res/drawable/rounded_edittext.xml -->
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle" 
       android:padding="10dp">

       <solid android:color="#FFCC00"/>

       <corners
         android:bottomRightRadius="3dp"
         android:bottomLeftRadius="3dp"
         android:topLeftRadius="3dp"
         android:topRightRadius="3dp"/>
</shape>
```

I would like to do the same thing for the button text such that when the button is in a pressed or focused state then the text is changed from black to yellow.

the when the button is but with regards to it's text. Below is my unsuccessful attempt to do this using the setOnFocusChangeListener:

```
    btnLogin.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            btnLogin.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        } else {
            btnLogin.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFCC00"));
        }
    }
});
```

I also tried using the button's setOnTouchListener to monitor the event and the change the text color accordingly but this was also unsuccessful:

```
    btnLogin.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (hasFocus) {
                btnLogin.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            } else {
                btnLogin.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFCC00"));
            }
    }
});
```

Any ideas as to how I could solve my issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey try this code i have tested and working fine when i press button its change color to yellow  and when you release its back to black color :)

```
btnLogin.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                btnLogin.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFCC00"));
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                btnLogin.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: @andrubot: thanks for the reply and your suggestion worked. cheers